# Javascript key-down keep tracking till second if statement is true

Tags: javascript

How do I succeed in making key press keep tracking till second if statement is true.

Here is my script:

```
document.onkeydown = KeyPressed;

var TestLeftPos = 5;
var Test2LeftPos = 0;

function KeyPressed(k) {

    var TestLeftPosTrack = 0;

    var LeftBtn = 37;
    var RightBtn = 39;
    var UpBtn = 38;
    var DownBtn = 40;

    if (k.keyCode == RightBtn) {

        if (TestLeftPosTrack == 40) {
            Test2LeftPos = Test2LeftPos - 0.5;
            document.getElementById("TestTwo").style.left = Test2LeftPos + "vw";
        }

        else if !(TestLeftPosTrack == 40) {

        TestLeftPos = TestLeftPos + 0.5;
        TestLeftPosTrack = TestLeftPosTrack + 0.5;
        document.getElementById("Test").style.left = TestLeftPos + "vw";

        }

    }

}
```

The problem is though that when the right button is clicked, it should keep carrying out the else statement till the original if statement is finally correct. When it is correct, it should immediately stop carrying out the else statement and start carrying out the original if statement but instead, it just carry's out the else statement all the way regardless of whether the original if statement is currently true. How do I fix this?

Comment: You create a variable `var TestLeftPosTrack = 0;` and then check if `TestLeftPosTrack == 40`. So you're checking if `0 == 40` which will always be false. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here

Comment: This is interesting... `else if !(TestLeftPosTrack == 40) {` Why not just do `!==` ?

Comment: You want to increment TestLeftPos and TestLeftPosTrack by 0.5 until it reaches 40 and than jump into the TestLeftPosTrack == 40 if statement?

Comment: Reijo, that is exactly what i want to do!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increment TestLeftPos and TestLeftPosTrack until 40 you should just loop.

Edit: As for or while loops block the event loop and callstack, they can be seen as an antipattern since we are responding to events.
Instead, window.setInterval(function, time) is a better fit, thanks to its async nature.

```
document.addEventListener('onkeydown', KeyPressed);
// in case you want to break loop if key up
var breakLoop = false;
document.addEventListener('onkeyup', function(event) {
  console.log('up');
  breakLoop = true;
});

var TestLeftPos = 5;
var Test2LeftPos = 0;

function KeyPressed(k) {
  console.log('down');
  var TestLeftPosTrack = 0;

  var LeftBtn = 37;
  var RightBtn = 39;
  var UpBtn = 38;
  var DownBtn = 40;

  var test1 = document.getElementById("Test");

  if (k.keyCode === RightBtn) {
    // set the interval
    var id = window.setInterval(() => {
      if (!breakLoop && TestLeftPosTrack < 40) {
        // setting a global variable can cause bugs
        // if a second interval is called before the original interval was cleared
        // you could scope the variable properly or
        // store it in a map with the interval id as the key
        // eg.: testLeftPosMap[id] += 0.5;
        TestLeftPos = TestLeftPos + 0.5;
        TestLeftPosTrack = TestLeftPosTrack + 0.5;
        test1.style.left = TestLeftPos + "vw";
      } else {
        window.clearInterval(id);
        Test2LeftPos = Test2LeftPos - 0.5;
        document.getElementById("TestTwo").style.left = Test2LeftPos + "vw";
      }
   }, 1);
}
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer, than you should accept it.